# White page appears although the widget is built

Tags: flutter, dart

When running this code I see a white page for 5 seconds then the loading page for a moment and then the home page. I expected to see the loading page for 5 seconds. I think the problem is in the code of the loading page. Is there a way I can see the loading page for 5 seconds?

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/home.dart';
import 'pages/loading.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/loading',
      routes: {
        '/loading': (context) => const Loading(),
        '/home': (context) => const Home(),
        },
    )
  );
}
```

loading page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';


class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  const Loading({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Loading> createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
      body: SafeArea(child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/loadingBackground.JPG'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a problem in your `didChangeDependencies`

make it as following

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
      });
  });}
```

The reason your loading screen was not showing is that `Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));` was working, but on its own. Separately so to say, and now it waits for 5 seconds, runs build method, then Navigator does its job. I tested, and it worked on my computer